# Why when textarea not fill, doesn't change a style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

When I press the button, I am trying to change styles of the textarea if it is not filled. But It doesn't work. I catch all elements in the form - textarea. But after this code doesn't work and I can't find a mistake.

```js
var btnForm = document.getElementById('btn-form');
btnForm.addEventListener('click', function (){
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var elems = form.elements;
var error=document.getElementById('error');
console.log(elems);

  for (var i=0; i < elems; i++){
      var textarea=elems[i];

      console(textarea);
      if (textarea.value==''){
          console.log('fserf');
        textarea.style.border = '2px solid red';
        error.style.display = "block";
      } 
  }
}
);
```

```css
.form{
    margin-top:30px;
    text-align: center;  
}
.form textarea{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #5dc5ef;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    resize: none;
}
.form button{
    padding: 10px 80px;    
}
.form-for-users h5{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#number-light-blue{
    color:#5dc5ef;
    font-size: 2em;
}
.btn-form{

}
#error{
    display: none;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" id="form">

                    <textarea type="text" class="form-control">:שם</textarea>
                    <textarea type="text" class="form-control">:מייל</textarea>
                    <textarea type="text" class="form-control">:נושא</textarea>
                    <textarea type="text" class="form-control">:הודעה</textarea>
                    <h5 id="error">Please, fill the form!</h5>
                </form>
                <button id="btn-form">שליחה</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to compare a number to an array:

`for (var i=0; i < elems; i++){`

Instead you're looking for:

`for (var i=0; i < elems.length; i++){`